# Android XML align overlapping text

Tags: android, xml, overlapping

So you can understand my point, here's an image:
[image]

So, the CODE (A) is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >   

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bag"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Title of product"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:lines="2"
        android:gravity="left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_product"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Model..." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title_product"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="10,99€"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="13dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the CODE (B):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >   

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bag"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price_product"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:text="Title of product"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:lines="2"
        android:gravity="left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_product"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Model..." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="10,99€"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="13dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the 'Title Product' is overlapping the 'Price'. What is the best approach to achieve what I want in the first image?

Comment: Looks to me like you should just swap around 'model' and 'price' in version B. Alternatively, just add a `toLeftOf` (to the 'title' with respect to the 'price) in version A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:padding="5dip" >   

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >   

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bag"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title of product"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:gravity="left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="Model..." />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="10,99€"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="13dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can put ellipsize at the end of the line or you need to make yout TextView in multiline, I mean you need to allow your textview to find new line when its done with line 1.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

May be it will work for you.